# How to define which join a dimension is using in ssas

Tags: ssas, dimensions

I have a sales fact table with two dates:  order received and order shipped.

I have a time dimension table in the data source view.

I have defined two relationships between the time dimension table and the sales fact table, one on order received date and order shipped date.

In the Cube definition I have two dimensions defined:  one for order date and one for shipping date.

I have time hierarchy defined for both dimensions (the fiscal calendar).

I can't figure out which relationship either of the dimensions are using.  It would appear that they are both using the join to order received date.  How do I tell SSAS to use the shipping date for one dimension and the order received date for the other.

Thanks,  --sw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would open the Cube source in Visual Studio / BIDS, then open the relevant Cube object and navigate to the Dimension Usage tab.

Then find the intersection of the Dimension (row) and Measure Group (column) and click the Build (...) button for that cell.  That will show you which columns are involved and let you select the correct Measure Group column.

When you first add a Dimension to a Cube, SSAS defines these settings using the Data Source View relationships (if any exist).

Comment: Thanks. That just saved me some time :)